# Unexpected result of Elastic term query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elastic 2.4 running on http://localhost:9200 only for test.

### Setup

As fresh start, I created 1 and only 1 item in the index.

```
$ curl -s -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d'
{
    "title": "The Godfather",
    "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "year": 1972,
    "genres": ["Crime", "Drama"]
}'
```

Returns

```
{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":"1","_version":3,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":false}
```

I then run this command to confirm the index works:

```
$ curl -s -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/movies/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "Godfather"
        }
    }
}'
```

Returns

```
{"took":8,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":0.095891505,"hits":[{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":"1","_score":0.095891505,"_source":
{
    "title": "The Godfather",
    "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "year": 1972,
    "genres": ["Crime", "Drama"]
}}]}}
```

### The Problem

I tried to run term query like this:

```
$ curl -s -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/movies/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "term": {"title": "The Godfather"}
    }
}'
```

I was expected to get 1 result, instead I got this:

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

What did I got wrong?

Comment: The `title` field is analyzed, so try a `match` query instead of `term` ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I want to find items which `title` matches exactly `"The Godfather"`, so `match` don't seems to fit my need. Is there anyway I can make term query work with the given data?

Comment: Try a match_phrase instead . https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `match_phrase` like jay suggested or you need to create a `not_analyzed` sub-field (e.g. `title.raw`), like this:

```
$ curl -s -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/_mapping/movie" -d'
{
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
               "raw": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Then you can reindex your document to populate the `title.raw`:

```
$ curl -s -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d'
{
    "title": "The Godfather",
    "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "year": 1972,
    "genres": ["Crime", "Drama"]
}'
```

And finally, your term query will work on the `title.raw` sub-field:

```
$ curl -s -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/movies/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "term": {"title.raw": "The Godfather"}
    }
}'
```